# Arithmetic operation with temp field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do some arithmetic in query using temporary field.

```
SELECT point, '5' AS bonus, (bonus*2) AS total FROM arithmetic
```

but the temp field is unknown

```
Unknown column 'bonus' in 'field list'
```

how to use or called temp field in query?

Comment: `SELECT point, 5 AS bonus, (SELECT bonus * 2) AS total FROM arithmetic;` but this will not work with aggregation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use a user variable here to store the valus of bonus, or use a subquery/CTE.  Assuming the latter, and that you are running MySQL 8+, we can try:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT point, 5 AS bonus
    FROM arithmetic
)

SELECT point, bonus, 2*bonus AS total
FROM cte;
```

Comment: thanks a lot!, its working using subquery